# default timezone is not working for sequelize querys in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone, sequelize.js

I set the timezone when i create the connection with sequelize but is not working in any query.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        host:process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        timezone: '-03:00'
    }
);

await sequelize.query(
       `UPDATE public.usuarios set data_disponibilidade = now() where id_usuario = $id_usuario`,
       {
           bind: {
               id_usuario: id_operador,
           },
           type: QueryTypes.UPDATE,
       }
   );
```

`now()` function is using the 00:00 timezone, ignoring the -03:00 that i setted before.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out where was my problem. The type of column was `timestamp with time zone`. and he ignore every time zone that i try to set after. Not even `'SET TIME ZONE 'America/Bahia'; '` was working in this specifically column. I changed the type for `timestamp without time zone` and now the `timezone` option is working for this column too. I just needed to look for the other tables to see that was an isolated problem in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `timezone` on the `dialectOptions` property for reads, setting it on the top level options is for writes.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectOptions: { // for reading
          useUTC: false,
          timezone: '-03:00',
        },
        timezone: '-03:00', // for writing
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i was already using in a write context. I added the code and still saving in the db with the timezone 00:00.

Comment: Did you specify `useUTC: false`?

Comment: I added `useUTC: false` inside and outside `dialectOptions`.

Comment: still saving with +3 hours from my timezone: `2020-11-06 18:12:11.764194`

Comment: Hmm, this works for me using MariaDB, maybe it's something weird with Postgres... this issue is still open https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/854

Comment: Do you have a timezone specified for the server? When you are viewing the value does the client you are using have a timezone setting? Dates can be tricky...

Comment: the client that i'm using, dont have a timezone setted. i tested with and without `'SET TIME ZONE 'America/Bahia';'` before i execute the UPDATE, and when i set before each one. the time is storaged like i want.

Comment: Try setting `timezone: 'America/Bahia'`?

Comment: i figured out where was my problem. the type of column was `timestamp with time zone`. and he ignore every time zone that i try to set after. not even `'SET TIME ZONE 'America/Bahia'; '` was working in this specificly column. I changed the tipe for `timestamp without time zone` and now the `timezone` option is working for this column too.

Comment: I just needed to look for the other tables to see that was an isolated problem in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
UPDATE public.usuarios set data_disponibilidade = now() AT TIME ZONE '+3:00' where id_usuario = $id_usuario
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't want specify what timezone in each query. I'm trying to use the default timezone that i setted at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define timezone in both dialect options and outside. It works for me, otherwise, it's not working for timezone like + 05:30

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
`${process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE}`,
`${process.env.MYSQL_USER}`,
`${process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}`,
{
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    define: {
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    },
    dialectOptions: { // for reading
        useUTC: false,
        timezone: 'Asia/Colombo'
    },
    host: `${process.env.MYSQL_HOST}`,
    useUTC: false,
    timezone: 'Asia/Colombo'
}
);
```